# Python Panda.read_csv rounds to get import errors?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 10000 x 250 dataset in a csv file. When I use the command

```
    data = pd.read_csv('pool.csv', delimiter=',',header=None)
```

while I am in the correct path I actually import the values.
First I get the Dataframe. Since I want to work with the numpy package I need to convert this to its values using

```
data = data.values
```

And this is when i gets weird. I have at position [9999,0] in the file a -0.3839 as value. However after importing and calculating with it I noticed, that Python (or numpy) does something strange while importing.

Calling the value of data[9999,0] SHOULD give the expected -0.3839, but gives something like -0.383899892....

I already imported the file in other languages like Matlab and there was no issue of rounding those values. I aswell tried to use the .to_csv command from the pandas package instead of .values. However there is the exact same problem.

The last 10 elements of the first column are

```
-0.2716
0.3711
0.0487
-1.518
0.5068
0.4456
-1.753
-0.4615
-0.5872
-0.3839
```

Is there any import routine, which does not have those rounding errors?

Answer (score 0):

That's a floating point error. This is because of how computers work. (You can look it up if you really want to know how it works.) Don't be bothered by it, it is very small.

If you really want to use exact precision (because you are testing for exact values) you can look at the decimal module of Python, but your program will be a lot slower (probably like 100 times slower).

You can read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

You should know that all languages have this problem, only some are better in hiding it. (Also note that in Python3 this "hiding" of the floating point error has been improved.)

Since this problem cannot be solved by an ideal solution, you are given the task to solve it yourself and choose the most appropriate solution for your situtation

I don't know about 'round_trip' and its limitations, but it probably can help you. Other solutions would be to use `float_format` from the `to_csv` method. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: The problem is, that i would understand this if the actual value is -0.383899892...., but it is the other way around. I have the "nice" value -0.3839 in the file and get the long floating number. 
The biggest issue is, that because of that i have an error of about 1% already at a set of 10000 datasets. This issue gets even worse, if i actually have number with 8 or even more decimal places.

And furthermore I don't understand why it works with other languages like Matlab that easily.

Comment: @Killuah13 I included more info

Answer (score 0):

Passing `float_precision='round_trip'` should solve this issue:

```
data = pd.read_csv('pool.csv',delimiter=',',header=None,float_precision='round_trip')
```